# Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on virtualbox

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization, 22.04

As the title say I'm unable to install 22.04 LTS on virtualbox as I get past the installation phase and I reboot as needed. Then I don't see anything but Ubuntu logo. (I followed the tutorial in the Ubuntu website)

[image: what I see]

Would love a solution, thx

Edit:

After reboot I only see black screen (after briefly seeing the Desktop), maybe graphics settings compatibility problem?
Here are the setting I use:
Using 2 monitors
[image: setting]

Edit 2:

After increasing the video memory to 128MB the screen works (if I don't change resolution from VB) but no mouse or keyboard input is working.

Comment: @guiverc The setting are capped to 128MB, using Intel iRIS Xe on a laptop if helps. Using 128MB does sometimes makes the screen show up but Its not consistent and when I change resolution it goes back to black screen.

Comment: Just to say I have what seems to be the same problem. I have a machine with a number of Ubuntu flavours running in VirtualBox VMs. All 22.04 versions work but not vanilla Ubuntu. I have tried both an upgrade from 20.04 and a clean install. The screen works OK but I can't log in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just my 5 cents. I had the system hanging at random points during the 22.04 installation process in VirtualBox. The problem was solved by increasing the system memory to 2048 MB and video memory to 128 MB.

Comment: Tried it before (see edit 2) and used 8192MB Memory but the screen got stuck at loading/Desktop. Did a clean reinstall with this settings and now it works for some reason. Also changed the 2 screens setting back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved my problem by changing the Graphics Controller to VMSVGA, which is the recommended setting.

However, this did raise a couple of other issues. In order to get auto-resizing to work I had to:

- Install `virtualbox-guest-x11`. I didn't need that when using VboxVGA.
- Select *Ubuntu on Xorg* when logging in, not the default *Wayland*.

Comment: While I was able to install Ubuntu, boot it, and load the Ubuntu homescreen/desktop, the sidebar was missing, the mouse didn't work, and none of the buttons in the top menu bar were clickable. The problem came from following Ubuntu's instructions that say to change the graphics-controller in the VM settings from the default VMSVGA to VBoxSVGA. Don't do this! Keep VMSVGA and change the display resolution in Ubuntu.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to that answer. I wanted to clarify that Ubuntu's installation instructions recommend using VBoxSVGA instead of the default VMSVGA and that these instructions were the source of my problem. Link to Ubuntu's instructions:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox#4-changing-the-window-resolution

Answer (score 0):

I have done just as [Andrey](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404950) said, but it didn't solved the problem until I upgraded virtual box to the last version. It solved my problem.

Comment: Good start but it would be helpfull to specify the version you upgraded to.  'Last version' will not remain last.