# Ubuntu 22.04 seems to freeze in Virtualbox 6.1 on Windows 11

Tags: virtualbox, windows

I have windows 11, and I downloaded virtualbox and installed Ubuntu 22 04. I followd [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQy9AUVuyF0&t=1s) step by step.

Ubuntu finished installation without any issues, but when I try to run it, it seems to get stuck. I am including a snapshot below:

[image]

I have tried restarting my computer, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help with the solution? Thanks in advance.

PS I have looked at posts such as [Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404017/unable-to-install-ubuntu-22-04-lts-on-virtualbox) But does not seem to solve my problem

Comment: Virtualbox on Windows has "issues" with freezing Linux guests. Checkout the virtual box log for details and post them directly here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker

Comment: mine is fixed after 6.1.36 r152435 (Qt5.6.2) upgrade

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  Windows OS must have Hyper-V services turned off, as well as Windows Linux System. Screen will show the V-chip icon in grey if issues there.

Also, I had downgraded to 6.1.34 same prob, but didn't realize the Extension pack was NOT down-graded. I downgraded first to try with a fresh VM install using 20.04 64 bit, same thing Freeze/hangs, then as I downgraded I got Applicatino memory access errors.

Lastly, I downgraded BOTH virtualbox and extension pack to 6.1.30, still using 20.04 and problems seemed to go away, TBD, works but will test out more.. since I wasted a day of time !?!?

Why can't virtualbox have BETTER ERROR and config checking to tell you :

1. Your extension pack doesn't match the version of VB A?? .. and/or:
2. Tell you that Hyper-V services or Windows System for Linux is running ???

Comment: Don't understand your answer: do you have a clear solution?

Comment: Yeah, not an answer.